# ngAfterViewChecked is not late enough

Tags: angular, materialize, lifecycle

I'm using materialize as a substitute to bootstrap.

I have a problem in which a select's options are not yet loaded, in which case calling materialize's initialization will not display correctly:

given my data:

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-form',
      templateUrl: './form.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./form.component.sass']
    })
    export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
      inputTest= {
        value: 1,
        choiceValues: [1,2,3,4]
      };
    }
```

the following html:

```html
      <select [(ngModel)]='inputTest.value' [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let choiceValue of inputTest.choiceValues">
          <option [ngValue]="choiceValue">{{choiceValue}}</option>
        </ng-container>
      </select>
```

with the following :

```js
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if (this.needsInitialization) {//just a guard to have the initialization once
      this.needsInitialization = false;
      
        let elems: NodeListOf<Element> = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('select');
        M.FormSelect.init(elems, {});
  }
```

will display (weirdly, all options are visible!):

[image]

and on click:

[image]

Using a setTimeout will work:

```js
      ngAfterViewChecked() {
        if (this.needsInitialization) {
          this.needsInitialization = false;
            setTimeout(() => {
              let elems: NodeListOf<Element> = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('select');
              M.FormSelect.init(elems, {});
            }, 1000);
    }
```

[image]

As per: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence
**ngAfterViewChecked** is the last sequence before **ngDestroy**. but it does not do what it promises: having loaded the view **completely**.

How do I use something better than a timeout, when angular's lifecycle is not working properly?

Comment: Why are you manipulating the native HTML? Is it not an option to use ‘The Angular Way ™️“..?

Comment: Materialize require Element objects, so I'd need to query the native html to have them. I do not know a better way to do or how it would translate the "angular way". Is there a way to apply a function on an element, when it's completely loaded?  does an element (like a select) send an event I could catch when it is?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you need, but maybe simply using Angular Material gets you where you want..?

Comment: Hmm, well I need to pack up the project in two-three days, I'm not really sure switching UI library so far in the timeline is wise.
I've still found a way around with setTimeOut(), so it's not a really big problem.

Comment: It’s the same css really.. and the interactive components are the same, only done in the official Angular way (Angular Material is actually supported by the core team). I’m afraid using these hacks will bite you later. Just saying man..

Comment: tks for the tip, I'll definitely keep it in mind